# How to accept alert using javascript in selenium robot framework

Tags: javascript, selenium, robotframework

I need your expertise to get some solution to my problem. there is an automated alert popup is generating while I am deleting some records. I have to use javascript in my selenium robot framework script to click OK on alert popup. I tried using following javascript codes. but didn't work. I know some of these are not correct, but tried anyway. Can you please help me resolve my issue.

```
Execute Javascript window.alert('alert text').apply()
Execute Javascript window.alert.apply()
Execute Javascript window.alert('alert text').click()
```

Thank you for your time and help
Yougander K

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the java snippet, you can use this.

```
Alert alert = new WebDriverWait(SELENIUM_WEBDRIVER, 30, 100).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
alert.accept(); //if you want to click ok
alert.dismiss(); //if you want to close alert message
```